Is it possible to add vertical scroll to TextField select options?
I'm using MUI in my project and I have this form in a modal with a select TextField component in it. Since there is 20 options for this select, depending on the screen size, the options list sometimes (vertically) overflows the modal. I would like the options list to be scrollable if it overflows the modal. Is it doable with a MUI TextField ?
Here is the TextField code simplified :
<TextField select
           label="My Label"
           variant="outlined"
           sx={styles.textField}
           value={myValue}
           onChange={handleChange}
         >
    {myMenuItems.map((item) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={item.key}
          value={item.key}
        >
          {item.content}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
</TextField>


I think you can set max-height to your select option list and overflow-y auto.
So you can do like this:

<TextField select
           label="My Label"
           variant="outlined"
           sx={styles.textField}
           value={myValue}
           onChange={handleChange}
    SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            MenuListProps: {
              sx: { maxHeight: 200, overflowY: 'auto' } // Your custom max-height
            },
          },
        }}
         >
    {myMenuItems.map((item) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={item.key}
          value={item.key}
        >
          {item.content}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
</TextField>


Feel free to ask.

Thank you very much ! It's not exactly what I wanted since I have to define a maxHeight where I was aiming for something automatic with the parent component size, but it will do the trick for now.

Update : having a dynamic maxHeight (100 vh - the number of pixels aroung my modal) gave me what I needed, I will approve this answer.
